# Array.Sort() not preserving element order with case-insensitive comparer

Tags: c#, sorting, ignore-case

I am using `Array.Sort()` with the parameters shown in the code. I'm unable to get the required order for the following array

```
jONeS
jones
joNes
jones
aDaMs
adams
adaMS
ADAMs
```

The program shown prints the following

```
adams
aDaMs
adaMS
ADAMs
jONeS
jones
joNes
jones
```

Where as according to me the following order should be printed

```
aDaMs
adams
adaMS
ADAMs
jONeS
jones
joNes
jones
```

Note the first two elements displayed wrongly.
Where am I going wrong?

```
int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string[] arr=new string[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    arr[i] = Console.ReadLine();
Array.Sort(arr, StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("en-US"),true));
Console.WriteLine();
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
```

Comment: Am I the only one who look at `ADAMs` and ask  , how come it is in different color ?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want the order of your elements preserved when they compare equal? If so, `Array.Sort()` uses Quicksort, which is not a stable sort. As long as two elements compare equalish (and this is the case for all the Adamses and Joneses) *any* output where the Adamses come before the Joneses is correct. If you additionally wish to preserve the original order of the elements, you need a stable sort algorithm like Mergesort.

Answer (score 3):

As Jeroen Mostert said Array.Sort is unstable ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)) however `OrderBy` in LINQ is stable ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422(v=vs.110).aspx)) you could use that.

So replace

```
Array.Sort(arr, StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("en-US"),true));
```

with

```
arr = arr.OrderBy(name=>name, StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("en-US"),true)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Of course `OrderBy`doesn't actually sort the array but rather creates a new one. But that might very well work for the op.